Cabinet doors "rock" when I open them
I recently moved into a new apartment, and I've noticed that four of the cabinet doors "rock" when I open them. It's subtle, and I didn't notice it at first, but then one of the screws actually fell out of one of the hinges! This is because the screws that go into the hinges are loose, and as the hinge rocks, it pushes the screws out.
Here's a GIF of it: https://imgur.com/a/R0BcF8O

What can I do to fix this? I'd prefer to fix it myself just to learn, but please tell me if the risk of damaging the cabinets further is significant because I can just notify the landlord instead.
I removed one of the doors, and I think I understand what's causing the issue. These must have been installed wrong. The hinge attaches to a metal plate, and that metal plate has three holes for screws. But the installer only put in the front two screws. This is why the door "rocks": the metal plate really needs three points of connection to be stable.



The screws are backing out of the metal parts, or the screws mounting the hinge to the cabinet?

The two horizontal screws that attach the door part of the hinge to the frame part of the hinge are loose. They should be pretty easy to tighten up with a Phillips or a slotted screwdriver. Some of the screws on that hinge are not standard issue so it might be good to let the landlord fix it. If the wood or metal has been striped, you don't want to be blamed for doing it. Just watch the repair for your learning experience.

Thanks. So I actually already tried re-screwing in the horizontal latches, but they just came undone. Makes me think the hole threads are no good or the screw is too small? But yeah, maybe I should tell the landlord

So for one cabinet, the bottom screws just fell out due to wobbling. So I just re-screwed them in, and even when they're fully into the hole, the horizontal latch wobbles back and forth (horizontally). Maybe I need bigger screws?

@jds Those screws probaby came with the hinge.  The screw on the left might move the door back and forth with the right screw locking it in place.  You might have to unscew them all to see how the hinge works...

Jack your advice to unscrew the door was key. Thanks. I've edited my comment above to explain what I'm pretty sure is happening.

The screws in your original post don't look like original equipment. Look at some of the other doors for the right screws and remove one and take it to your home store to get the additional screws.  Good job.
